# How to convert IPv4 address to decimal

Tags: c

Is there a function to convert an IPv4 address in dotted decimal notation (e.g., "192.168.0.1") into a decimal value?

There are several questions similar to this, but all are looking for or have answers that involve writing a function to solve the answer.  I'm looking for an existing function in a library.

Comment: If you by "decimal value" mean an "integer value representing the address", then yes there are. And just about any book or tutorial (even pretty bad ones) should contain the information. As would probably a very quick search in your favorite search engine.

Comment: 4 parts each for 8 bits (values from 0 to 255) - it's not really hard to write your own function to convert string `a.b.c.d` into number `(a << 24) + (b << 16) + (c << 8) + d`.

Comment: @ventaquil `a << 24` can overflow, use `(uint32_t)a << 24`. Cast the other parts as well if this must work on a platform with less than 32bit `int`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen good tip. I wanted to show an idea - not complete solution.

Comment: "*I'm looking for an existing function in a standard library.*" <- in **a** standard library? There's only one C standard library specification, and it doesn't include such a function. But it's really not too complicated to write one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Winsock 2 provides the [`inet_addr()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-inet_addr) function, which simply returns the equivalent decimal value for the address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* pAddr = "192.168.0.1";

    unsigned long value = inet_addr(pAddr);

    if (value == INADDR_NONE)
        printf("Invalid format of IP address");
    else
        printf("Decimal representation of %s is: %lu", pAddr, value);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The C standard library doesn't have such a function. It's simple enough that this shouldn't be a problem. Here's some example code using `strtoul()` for parsing:

```
int parseIpv4Address(uint32_t *addr, const char *addrStr)
{
    const char *p = addrStr;
    char *endp;

    unsigned long a = strtoul(p, &endp, 10);
    if (*endp != '.') return -1;
    unsigned long b = strtoul(p = endp+1, &endp, 10);
    if (*endp != '.') return -1;
    unsigned long c = strtoul(p = endp+1, &endp, 10);
    if (*endp != '.') return -1;
    unsigned long d = strtoul(p = endp+1, &endp, 10);
    if (*endp) return -1;

    *addr = (uint32_t) ((a << 24) | (b << 16) | (c << 8) | d);
    return 0;
}
```

as `unsigned long` must have at least 32 value bits, there's no special care (casting) needed for the shifts here.

It doesn't validate the range of the individual parts, if you need this, you should be able to add it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `inet_pton` which is pretty straight forward to use as you can see from the example code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
    {
    struct in_addr result;

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&result))
        {
        printf("%08x\n",result.s_addr);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("Failed\n");
        }
    return(0);
    }
```

The number is in network byte order, but if you want it in host byte order, you can use `ntohl` to convert it.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  There's an even simpler solution though with `inet_addr`.

Comment: @Ian it is simpler, but doesn't provide a usable means of identifying errors